# systemd analyze blame says Excess arguments

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

My Ubuntu 16.04 takes long time to boot, so I tried to figure out what is the problem. When I run `systemd analyze blame`, it says `Excess arguments` in red color. What can be wrong with my system?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com Also, no indication is made that the poster has otherwise researched what this error message means.

Comment: With all respects sir! i did search alot,there was similar cases out there,but neither could solve my problem,if a thing is easy to find in google why should i have accepted extra pain in my neck by posting it here?

Answer (score 1):

I searched the systemd code base for the string "Excess arguments." which helped find the answer. It says it is emitted when *"we aren't run as an init system"*

That seems strange and unrelated until I looked twice at what you ran. You ran:

```
 systemd analyze blame
```

Which is a typo. You meant to run:

```
 systemd-analyze blame
```

The code comment turns out to be right on-- you were running `systemd` not as init system, making the `analyze` and `blame` arguments to be *excess*.